# From two dataframes inside a list, I need to substract two columns and get another dataframe

Tags: r, aggregate, diff

I have these dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame( value=c(1,2,3,4), income= c(12,14,51,12))
df2 <- data.frame( value=c(2,3,4,7), income= c(14,11,53,13))
```

I need to get this dataframe:

```
df3
  value income
1   1   -12
2   2   0
3   3   -40
4   4   41
5   7   13
```

But I used aggregate function and I get this:

```
df3 <-do.call(rbind, l)%>% aggregate(income ~ value, ., FUN=diff)

  value income
1   1   numeric(0)
2   2   0
3   3   -40
4   4   41
5   7   numeric(0)
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base R answer.

```
df3 <- merge(df2, df1, by = "value", all = TRUE)
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0
df3[["income"]] <- df3[["income.x"]] - df3[["income.y"]]
```

tidyverse answer.

```
library("tidyverse")

df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "value") %>%
  replace_na(list(income.x = 0, income.y = 0)) %>%
  mutate(income = income.x - income.y)
```

data.table answer.

```
library("data.table")

DT1 <- data.table(value=c(1,2,3,4), income= c(12,14,51,12))
DT2 <- data.table(value=c(2,3,4,7), income= c(14,11,53,13))

DT3 <- merge(DT1, DT2, by = "value", all = TRUE)
DT3[is.na(DT3)] <- 0

DT3[, income := income.x - income.y]
```

Comment: Excellent,it was a great solution. Thanks